# Woocommerce - get attribute value by variation ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating product headings for product XML feed. I need to get variation value by ID. Documentation says:

```
$text = apply_filters( 'xml_feeds_productname_variant', $text, $product_item->ID, $vars->ID );
```

So I got ID of variation and displayed it:

```
function custom_product_name( $text, $product_id, $vars_id ) {
    global $product;
    
    $product_name = $product->get_name();
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    
    $text = 'Example.com ' . $sku . ' ' . $product_name . ' ' . $vars_id;         
    return $text; 
}
add_filter( 'xml_feeds_productname_variant', 'custom_product_name', 10, 3 );
```

Now I need to display variation value instead of `$vars_id` variable. If product has selected a variation with value 60x40cm, display "60x40cm" in heading instead of `$vars_id`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As is often the case, there are different ways, this is one of them.
- Note that the use of a global variable is not necessarily needed, because you have access to the `$product_id` you can get the product object via [`wc_get_product`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_get_product)

```php
function custom_product_name( $text, $product_id, $vars_id ) {
    // Get WC_Product_Variation Object
    $variation = wc_get_product( $vars_id );

    // Is a WC_Product
    if ( is_a( $variation, 'WC_Product' ) ) {       
        // Variation name
        $variation_name = implode( ' / ', $variation->get_variation_attributes() );
    
        // Output
        $text = 'Name: ' . $variation_name; 
    }
    
    return $text; 
}
add_filter( 'prefix_xml_feeds_productname_variant', 'custom_product_name', 10, 3 );
```